# How to share file located in Downloads directory?

Tags: android

I am trying to share files from my app to another using the android app picker but after choosing the recieving app, say, whatsapp I get a "format not compatible" error once inside the whatsapp app.

The file I intend to share is always located in the DOWNLOADS folder.

My code for sharing is:

```
private void share() {
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.file_provider_authority),
                new File(getContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/" + fileToShare.getFileName()));

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, fileToShare.getFileName()));
}
```

I know I need to use FileProviders because I'm targeting above V24 and believe this is the right way to do it but something must be missing because I keep getting this error.

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong so i can fix my code? Thank you!

Comment: @blackapps sorry, should be fixed now

Comment: You asked this before today isnt it?

Comment: What if you choose an email app?

Comment: `if (fileExists())` ??? What has that function to do with the file you use in the next lines? Unreadable code in this way.

Comment: `file I intend to share is always located in the DOWNLOADS folder.` In which Download folder? There can be more.

Comment: `File file = new File(getContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/" + fileToShare.getFileName())); if (!file.exists()) return; if (!file.canRead()) return; Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.file_provider_authority), file);` Please adapt your code do replace that bad fileExists(). Display a Toast at those returns to inform the user.

Comment: @blackapps 
Idid, but I asqued the wrong question
`fileExists()` is irrelevant, I forgot to delete it while editing this question for stackoverflow. 
The downloads folder I refer to is the one you can acces via `getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)`

Comment: Change your code and add the two checks. Add the toasts.

Comment: On most devices there is no such app private Download folder. Unless your app created it.

Comment: @blackapps The image i want to share isn't located in a private downloads folder

Comment: Then why do you use getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) as that would be apps private download folder.